# Clearing cookies in IE through Java

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, cookies, internet-explorer-11

Can someone suggest a way to clear the cookies in IE every time when we hit a specific URL. I am using Java springs MVC with Maven.

Can someone suggest a solution using Javascript/Java?

Answer (score 0):

you must know that the cookie management has nothing to do with the browser, if you manage cookies for a server-side session, you communicate to the browser the action he must do for this cookie.
And for your case to delete cookies you can do like that server side in java code

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length ; ++i) {
     if(cookies[i].getName().equals("cookie_name")){
       cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
       response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
       break;
   }
}
```